# bootstrap 3 navbar-fixed-top gets a top white margin when navbar is collapsed

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a webapp using the latest bootstrap (3.0.3). I created the navbar by copy pasting from bootstap docs, like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top green">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Smart Pigs</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="online-offline" toggle="offline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>&nbsp;Go offline</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://10.10.10.1/SmartPigs.apk" name="download"><span aria-hidden="true" class="agrosoft-download"></span>&nbsp;Update App</a>
            </li>
            <!-- <li>
                <a href="#" id="open"><span class="agrosoft-bluetooth"></span>&nbsp;Bluetooth</a>
            </li> -->
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

</nav><!-- end navbar -->
```

I am testing this on a mobile phone, and on a Nexus 7 tablet. Whenever I collapse my navbar I get a white margin on top of the navigation bar. If I close the menu, the white margin disappears.

I also noticed that If I put enough links in my navigation menu such that I need to scroll to the bottom of the navigation, the white line margin also disappears.

The problem is that my navigation only has 2 links and when I collapse it on my tablet I always get the top margin. It is very frustrating. I only see this behavior on my tablet. on the phone and pc browsers it works fine. I do not know what is wrong. Please help.